# RSpec should redirect_to problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing a spec for my Rails controller, this is the action I'm testing:

```
def create
  @course = Course.new(params[:course])
  if @course.save then
    #flash[:notice] = 'Course Created'
    redirect_to courses_path
  else
    render :action => 'new', :status => 400
  end
end
```

And this is the spec that validates it:

```
describe "POST /courses [Good Input]" do

  it "should redirect to Courses index page after creation" do
    @course.stub!(:save).and_return(true)
    post :create
    response.should be_success
    response.should redirect_to(courses_path)
  end

end
```

Still I'm getting this error from RSpec:

> 'CoursesController POST /courses [Good
> Input]
>
> should redirect to Courses
> index page after creation'

**FAILED**

> expected redirect to "/courses", got
> no redirect

Any ideas why this happens?

**SOLVED**

as **rishavrastogi** stated, *should be_success* expects a http code on the 2xx range, and a redirect falls into the 3xx range (actually its 302)

The assertion needs to be changed to => *response.should be_redirect*.

Although in this case, it's redundant to check that the response is a redirect and then checking that redirects to an specific page, so that assertion is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a RSpec-er either but I guess "response.should be_success" shouldn't be there because the response is actually a "HTTP redirect" not "HTTP success" ... so try removing response.should be_success

Also change

```
 post :create
```

to

```
 post :create, :course => {}
```

Comment: why should I change post :create?

Comment: actually that may not be required until you want to pass some values of instance variables for example "post :create ,:course => {:title=> "something" }.. " etc..this may be required when working with validations

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm mocking everything (like Course.new and Course.find)... so I really don't need that, but it's a good point anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a rspecer, but afaik you have to do something like `assigns(:course).stub!...`. Instance variables in specs aren't the same as instance variables in controllers, `assigns` so lets you access the controller ones.

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that in the before block I do Course.stub!(:new).and_return(@course) which is a dummy object I create...